# Apex Page Attributes - Performance Impact

Tags: visualforce, performance

I would like to better understand how each of the following attributes on an `apex:page` tag (or any notable omissions) affect load times.

- `applyBodyTag`
- `applyHtmlTag`
- `docType`
- `showHeader`
- `sidebar`
- `standardStylesheets`

In my discussions with other developers, there have been a lot of hand-wavy assumptions that:

- Setting `applyBodyTag` or `applyHtmlTag` to `true` is noticeably faster than `false`.
- Setting `showHeader`, `sidebar`, `standardStylesheets` to `false` is noticeably faster than `true`.
- Setting a `docType` of `html-5.0` is noticeably faster than other values.

I want some concrete numbers to back up (or disprove) these assumptions. Can anyone provide them?

My interpretation of @Ashwani's findings:

1. ~50ms `<apex:page>`
2. ~35ms `<apex:page applyBodyTag="false">`
3. ~ 9ms `<apex:page applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false">`
4. ~ 7ms `<apex:page applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" showHeader="false">`
5. ~30ms `<apex:page docType="html-5.0">`
6. ~32ms `<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been into the situation when deciding the view architecture. Here are some real figures based on various attributes used with `<apex:page>`

For example consider a page like this:

```
<apex:page ~~attribs~~ >
    Lot of text
    <label> I am </label>
    No adding apex tags as they have their on performance.
</apex:page>
```

Controller is a separate thing (has own processing) so, assume there is no controller in Visualforce page.

**1. No attribute** 
 A page with only html tags and no attribute added take around 50ms to load. Consider `50ms` the default loading time of page which has no attribute set explicitly.

**2. applyBodyTag attribute**  
 `applyBodyTag = false` attribute significantly increases the page loading time as now its browser or the developer's work to apply body tag properly. In comparison to `50ms` it takes around `35ms`.

**3. applyHtmlTag and showHeader attribute**  
 This faster than `applyBodyTag = false` as no header needs to be rendered by Visualforce engine. In comparison to last `35ms` it takes `9ms` to load a page.

**4. applyBodyTag and applyHtmlTag and showHeader attribute**  
 It reduces visualforce engine processing a little. In comparison to `9ms` it takes `7ms`.

**5. docType HTML-5.0**  
 This is true `HTML-5.0` is faster and in comparison to default (#6) it takes `30ms`.

**6. docType default**  
 It is slower than #5. Figure at "#1 No attribute" is similar to this `50ms-58ms`.

**7. showHeader attribute**  
 It is faster than `showHeader = true`.

**8. sidebar attribute**  
 When showHeader is false, sidebar automatically is false. It is faster the true values set.

**9 showHeader and sidebar attribute**  
 This is slower than showHeader and sidebar = `false`.

**10. standardStylesheets attribute**  
  This attribute does not make significant difference, but value = false is faster. Time will be reduces to few ms like if page take `35ms` to load wit will take `32ms` when set to false.

**12. showHeader and sidebar attribute but no standardStylesheets**  
 It is same as #10.

Also, longer the html text longer the processing time. More apex tags more processing time. Action functions, Action support, Remoting function and re-render increases page processing time a lot.

Comment: I think a couple of your descriptions are confusing or incorrectly worded. Can you double check my interpretation? I added it to my OP.

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson, your interpretation is correct. It basically explain performance of `<apexpage>` with attributes. Each attribute contribute to performance negatively/positively. So, using above figure you would easily figure out which attribute is heavier and which is lighter. I believe that you know that when `applyHtmlTag` is false then `showheader` is also `false`.  There are few more dependencies like this.

Answer (score -3):

The `applyHtmlTag` attribute is used to determine whether or not to include the HTML `<html>` tag at the beginning of the page. By default, Visualforce pages include the `<html>` tag. However, if you set `applyHtmlTag="false"`, Visualforce will omit the `<html>` tag from the generated page.

The `applyBodyTag` attribute works in a similar way but for the `<body>` tag. By default, Visualforce pages include the `<body>` tag to enclose the content of the page. If you set `applyBodyTag="false"`, Visualforce will omit the `<body>` tag from the generated page.

Example

<apex:page applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">

## Hello, Visualforce!

</apex:page>

In this example, the `<html>` and `<body>` tags will be omitted from the generated page, leaving only the content within the `<apex:page>` tag.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. I've downvoted this because it does not answer the question being asked here. The question isn't about what these attributes _do_, it's about _what impact they have on performance/load times_. It's important to thoroughly read the question and understand it before trying to write an answer.